# Yii2: Trying to generate a csv file with ajax

Tags: php, yii2, export-to-csv

Im trying to generate a basic csv file with some data. When I use an alert inside the ajax call it will show me the data(so there is data passing), but when I click the button it will not generate an CSV file. Im new to yii2 so im still learning.

**UPDATED**
I have changed the files

//view export/index.php

```
Pjax::begin();

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action'  => yii\helpers\Url::to(['cms-export/index']),
    'options' => ['data' => ['pjax' => true]],
    'layout'  => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label'   => 'col-sm-2',
            'offset'  => 'col-sm-offset-2',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-5',
            'hint'    => 'col-sm-5',
        ],
    ],
]);

    echo $form->field($model, 'language')->dropDownList([//some list]);

    echo $form->field($model, 'filename')->textInput()

    echo Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])';



ActiveForm::end();

Pjax::end();
```

//model

```
public function generateCsv(){

  header('Content-Type: application/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');

    $data = [datacomeshere];

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ( $data as $line ) {
        fputcsv($fp, $line, ';');
    }
    fclose($fp);

}
```

//controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $model = new Export();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

        // validation works, but method does not work
        \common\models\Export::generateCsv();

    }

    return $this->render('index' , ['model' => $model]);

}
```

When I click the button it will show me an 500 error in the jquery file

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

Comment: 'will not generate' ... what happens instead???

Comment: i see an 500 error in the jquery code

Comment: You could have a look into you log file. This error should have been logged.

Comment: If an error 500 occurs, there is mostly every time something written to your server's error log. Please locate that message and attach it to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach, removing the whole JS code:

Make the link a real one. It makes sense to have a GET request, since you just getting data with the call.

```
<div class="modal-button-row">
    <a href="cms-export/download" id="export-trigger" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Export</a>
</div>
```

Modify the action now (probably in CmsExportController) and use the [Yii download capability](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendContentAsFile()-detail):

```
public function actionDownload() {
    $csv = Export::generateCsvSomehow(); // this should return a csv string
    return \Yii::$app->response->sendContentAsFile($csv, 'sample.csv', [
           'mimeType' => 'application/csv', 
           'inline'   => false
    ]);
}
```

More infos in guide: [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-responses#sending-files).

You also need to remove [Pjax](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax), since it will do its own stuff with links and forms via JS! Or you have to configure Pjax, e.g. with [$formSelector](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax#$formSelector-detail), which goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Okay, nice but sadly this does nothing here, so am I missing something perhaps?

Comment: @user759235 What happens exatly?

Comment: @user759235 Does the action get called? Do you get a status 400?

Comment: @user759235 You may have to use `href="/cms-export/download"` if the actions does not get called. Or try `$csv = "asdf,fdsa";`. Did you have removed the JS code?

Comment: I have updated my examples, im now using activeform as i need some data to pass. You're example does also not work

Comment: @user759235 What does not work? Why don't you provide clearer information? Please describe what happens! And don't change your question that way

Comment: Well I cant say anything more as it does not do anything, the action works, but the method does not do anything...when i put the method in the view file it will work Update: i see an 500 error in the jquery code

Comment: when I use this ill get the error 'mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...'

Comment: @user759235 Because `$csv` doesn't seem to be a string. A string containing the whole content of the file is required.

Comment: I see, but this still does not work, both ways will now output plain text in the page, so data is passing but not as an file.

Comment: @user759235 Hm... Can you try another browser? Maybe it's a browser setting? `'inline' => false` should open the browser dialog for saving the download. What happens if you set it to `true`?

Comment: true or false it still show the data in the file, I do see an other error yii\base\ErrorException: Object of class yii\web\Response could not be converted to string...this error is even present when i use a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170594/discussion-between-robsch-and-user759235).

Comment: The issue was that pjax is not needed here, without pjax it will generate a working csv file. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

One problem is definitely that the regular action call always creates headers, cookies and some content (even an empty string, e.g. if you have forgotten the return statement with `$this->render(...)`) that gets sent to the browser. I supsect that you get some [Headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) error. So this has to be suppressed so that your CSV code takes control.

Try the following:

```
 public function actionIndex() {
    $model = new Export();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        \common\models\Export::generateCsv();
        Yii::$app->response->isSent = true;
    } else {
        return $this->render('index' , ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Btw: Use `method: GET` in your form if no data gets changed with that call. This is a HTTP standard. POST is used when something gets added or changed.

However, I would recommend [my other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50211690/57091) using [`Response::sendContentAsFile()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendContentAsFile()-detail). This should work with your ActiveForm as well. As noted in that answer you have to remove or configure Pjax.

Comment: Still not working, I still see the error 500 status code in the jquery file, the same error with the other solution

Comment: okay found the 500 error...wrong namespacing, but it's not saving as a file, it only shows as text